# send a full brokered message in azure service bus from an azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm facing issue to send a complete brokered message to an azure service bus output in azure function in javascript. 
The documentation only show a simple body message https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus without any customerProperties.

My attempts to create a full brokered message failed so far, everything goes into the body.

[image]
[image]

```
var message = {'body' : 'test', 'customProperties' : {'fromsystem':'sap'}};
context.bindings.outputSbMsg = message;
context.done(null, res);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is one of the limitations of node, as we lose some type information that we have in C#.

You could be trying to send a message with a `body` of `test` with custom properties, but you could also be trying to send the entire object as the body, with a `body` sub-property. Azure Functions make the assumption that everything that you return should go into the body.

As a workaround, you could:

- ditch the output binding and use the [ServiceBus sdk for node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node) directly
- instead of node, use C# or F# with the actual `BrokeredMessage` type
- have your node function put the result into a queue, which then triggers a C# function to create the exact `BrokeredMessage` you want

Comment: sad :) the integration was really easy. I might fallback to C# as you suggested. I thought about a 4th solution with an intermediate queue + rule & a SET property, but it's only possible for subscribers, not queues.

Comment: [C# approach] in order to add 'out BrokeredMessage outputSbMsg' in my Run method prototype, I had to switch from async to sync. I don't know if there is another way :/ but it's working :)

Comment: You could use the type IAsyncCollector<BrokeredMessage>.  Here are some other types you can use: https://jhaleyfiles2016.blob.core.windows.net/public/Azure%20WebJobs%20SDK%20Cheat%20Sheet%202014.pdf

Comment: Please state this limitation clearly in the documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#service-bus-output-binding. It took som googling, trial and error before I ended up here.

Comment: in order to be able to provide custom properties in an output binding, can we use this in c#?  `IAsyncCollector<BrokeredMessage>`